# force load background images even if the element is still hidden

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I'm wondering if there is a way to load background images right after everything else is loaded..

What i have is a slider that per slide has a background image and my problem is the background images only shows up or loaded once the slide is active or visible. I want them to be loaded so there will not be a moment that a slide will be empty.

Comment: Would it help to use `overflow: hidden` in a container as opposed to making the slides `display: hidden`?

Comment: What are you using for the slider? Your own code or some jQuery plugin? Please provide some code it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set css property of every slide `display :none;` this will enable you to download the background images but will be hidden. Once you open the slide change css to `display :block` This will solve your problem.